# How to concatenate 2 variables into a field name in Oracle Forms 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

How can I concatenate two variables and arrive at the field name in Oracle Forms 11g.

For e.g.I dont know the name of the field till runtime and I have 2 variables.

```
Var1 := 'blk1.fld_';
Var2 := 1;
```

Suppose there is a field in the form like blk1.fld_1 and I want to assign  it a value 'yes'.
Please tell me how to concatenate the 2 variables and assign the value to the field.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can succesively use **`Name_In`** and **`Copy`** functions those belongs to ***Forms*** but neither to ***PL/SQL*** nor to ***Oracle's SQL*** such as

```sql
Copy('yes',Name_In(Var1||Var2));
```

where

**`Name_In`** will return the content of that field, and

**`Copy`** will assign the value *`'yes'`* to the item **`blk1.fld_1`**